# Transmission of HIV through oral sex

Tags: hiv

What is the risk of HIV transmission to a girl who does a blow job (deep) if a man ejaculated into her mouth, where there were no wounds and brushing her teeth before intercourse?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences. Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For reasons [mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research) and in [How to Ask](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), we require questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. This also seems to violate the personal medical advice rule, but you'd need to make it clearer with your research that you're after the stats, not odds for personal circumstances.

Comment: The answer to this is all over the web. Just enter 'HIV oral sex' in a search engine.

Comment: @CareyGregory actually, this same question [was asked here on this very site](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/14598/what-is-the-risk-of-hiv-infection-via-insertive-fellatio) almost five years ago, and got a decent answer, one that you won't find in quick Google search. Maybe reopen and close as duplicate?